# Outlook VBA: PathSeparator Property Missing in Application Object

Tags: vba, outlook, path-separator

I am trying to use the Application.PathSeparator property.  But PathSeparator property is not available for selection and if I enter it in my VBA code I get Run-time error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.

Is there something I need to install to have access to PathSeparator?   I have MS Office 2007 and Outlook 2010.  I do not have .Net client installed.

Trying to use in sample code below:

```
Sub UnZipFile(strTargetPath As String, Fname As String)
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant

    If Right(strTargetPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        strTargetPath = strTargetPath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If

    FileNameFolder = strTargetPath
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(strTargetPath & Fname).items
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think that property should exist?  I.E. where you seen it before.  Show some references.

Comment: sorry about that.   I am trying to cycle through emails in a specific outlook folder to save attachments to a windows folder.  Some of the attachments are Excel files in zip files and others are just Excel.  So I have sample code to unzip which uses this property.   See code above in orig question:

Comment: Please don't paste code in comments.

Comment: Okay, I see your code.  What makes you think something should exist called `Application.PathSeparator`?  Where are you getting that notion from?

Comment: @roryap [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196366(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: That documentation seems to be for Word VBA, although it's not specific.  It's really terrible documentation, to be honest.  Shame on microsoft.  At any rate, properties in Word Application are not going to be the same as in Outlook Application.

Comment: @roryap it looks like it works for everything but outlook. Yea, inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

`PathSeperator` is not a property of `Outlook.Application`. If You really want to use `Application.PathSeperator`, you could add a reference to `Microsoft Excel x.0 Object Library` then add this code to the top of your project:

```
Dim exapp As Excel.Application
Set exapp = New Excel.Application
```

...and replace all instances of `Application.PathSeperator` with:

```
exapp.PathSeparator
```

...but that is probably the stupidest code I have ever written. All the `PathSeperator` property does is return the device depended Path Separator, so in windows it returns the string `\`. It was a property that was available in Excel VBA before Outlook got VBA, and it isn't really used anymore. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell) is a list of path seperators for different operating systems, if you are interested.

Here is the above code, working in Outlook:

```
If Right(strTargetPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    strTargetPath = strTargetPath & "\"
End If

FileNameFolder = strTargetPath
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oApp.NameSpace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(strTargetPath & Fname).Items
DoEvents
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Andrew.   This is a huge help.